# Java - Cómo quitar el punto del valor de una variable double al pasarla a String?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase persona con un campo `monto` declarado como `double`, a el cual realizo operaciones matemáticas.
Luego necesito concatenar todos los campos en una variable `String` y grabarlo en un fichero `.txt`.
Cómo puedo pasar el campo `double` a un `String` sin perder los decimales y quitar el punto?

> Por ejemplo, necesito esto:
>
> ```
> 1500.00     Muestre un String -> 150000
>
> 2050.50     Muestre un String -> 205050
>
> 1000.02     Muestre un String -> 100002
> ```
>
> Si uso String.ValueOf(monto) muestra con el . y con un solo decimal si
>   es 0.

Con `String.valueOf(monto).replaceAll("\\.","");` logro quitar el punto pero sigo teniendo el problema con la cantidad de decimales.
No puedo dar con el `String.format`. No he logrado lo que quiero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema se resuelve usando DecimalFormat, y haciendo uso de un poco de logica con cadenas... prueba el siguiente codigo.

```
double d = 2050.50;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String aux = format.format(d);//Obtenemos el valor neto usando el formateador

aux = aux.replaceAll(",","");//eliminamos las comas
```

Comment: Gracias, al principo me mostraba con coma. Pero ya esta solucionado. muchisimas gracias.
Por si alguien más busca esto. Así tuve que dejar para que me funcione.
String aux = myFormat.format(monto).replaceAll("\\,","");

Comment: Si te ha funcionado y ha resuelto tu duda estaría bien que la marcases como válida (se hace pulsando el tick verde bajo la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto servirá tanto al usuario que te ha ayudado como a los futuros usuarios que tuviesen la misma duda.

Comment: La segunda y tercera instrucción me ayudaron a arreglar mi código, la cuarta no fue necesaria, ya que al colocar un solo cero sin el punto decimal, en la declaración de format, da como resultado un número entero.